# How to solve “Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded" when getting list of all files using Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I wanted to get list of all non-trashed files in my Google Drive and therefore modified the example provided by Google: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list#examples

The example looks like this:

```
result = []
page_token = None

while True:
    try:
        param = {}
        param['q'] = 'trashed=false'
        if page_token:
            param['pageToken'] = page_token
        files = service.files().list(**param).execute()
        result.extend(files['files'])
        page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')
```

However, this resulted in the error: "HTTpError 400 when requesting.... returned "Invalid Value"" in my console and when following the html path it resulted in "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup error."

When the query is run without the "trashed=false" there is no issue and therefore the error of the daily limit exceeded seems to be wrong.

Comment: What is unclear about the error?

Comment: I mostly wanted to ask this question in order to answer it myself. Because it clearly wasn't a correct error, as I could run the query without the "trashed=false" and get the full list.   Figured I could help some people who happenedd to stumble upon this later.

Comment: FWIW I used to query a Google sheet every 2 seconds, 24/7 and never hit the API limit with a free account. That was 3 years ago.

Comment: Exactly, it clearly wasn't the problem

Comment: No, I edited sorry, I used credentials. Your answer also states that you don't know why it works.

Comment: I don't, but it DOES work, meaning others could use the same approach .

Comment: DOES work right now. You've already been given a potential reason under the answer. In any case, I don't think we're going to be productive keeping debating this. You _can_ have a free account and you're almost certainly not going up against Google and somehow cheating a system - you're just complying somehow... and you don't know the "how".

Comment: The error message is saying you are **unauthenticated**. Your code doesn't show how you are acquiring or using an Access Token.

Comment: service is created with the token as: service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

Comment: well something is going wrong. You think you are authenticated, Google doesn't. The error message is a standard one, and it means your http request has no Authorization header. It's nothing to do with quotas.

Answer (score -2):

I am not entirely sure why, but passing the arguments directly instead of using the dictionary "param" solved the issue!

Example:

```
        param = {}
        if page_token:
            param['pageToken'] = page_token
        files = service.files().list(q='trashed=false', pageToken=page_token).execute()
        result.extend(files['files'])
        page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')
```

Comment: Seems more likely that it's been a day and your daily limit has reset.

Comment: (Or that it hasn't been an entire day, but it's been long enough to hit a daily reset, or earlier API usage has fallen out of a 24-hour window or something.)

Comment: I can switch back between the method in the answer and the question and consistently get the error message only for the method in the answer. Within seconds that is, so I doubt that anything is resetting in that timeframe.